# batch file loop though services to disable

Tags: batch-file

I've put this string together to disable services;

sc query %service%| find "RUNNING" >nul 2>&1 && net stop %service% && sc config %service% start= disabled

Currently I have the actual service name instead of a variable. I would like to loop though a list in the batch enabling/disabling each

for %%a sc query "wsearch"| find "RUNNING" >nul 2>&1 && net stop "wsearch" && sc config "wsearch" start= disabled
Service1
service2
service3
)

Looping through each service name disabling it.
Any ideas? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo disable services*************
for %%x in (
"wsearch"
"Mcx2Svc"
"NetTcpPortSharing"
"SharedAccess"
"fax"
"TabletInputService"
"RemoteAccess"
"UxSms"
"Bdesvc"
"EFS"
"wmiApSrv"
) do sc query %%x| find %%x >nul 2>&1 && net stop %%x && sc config %%x start= disabled
```

Comment: This is a gem of a solution, but please be aware that if you run this on a remote machine, `RemoteAccess` being disabled won't let you login any more!

Comment: yes, that RemoteAccess wasn't left in there. I have a script I run every computer that I set up now that disables a lot of unnecessary services and it works great! reduces memory use, and reduces startup time. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Sure would like to have your full list! Can you add it? Would save me a ton of time.

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand your question, next code snippet might help:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem loop against a list of several service names
for %%G in (
    WinDefend
    "WSearch"
    FooBar
) do sc query "%%~G" >NUL && (
    rem next line merely for debugging:
    sc qc "%%~G" | find ":"
    rem instead of above line: 
    rem your code snippet to change the configuration of a service here
) || (
    rem perhaps the specified service does not exist as an installed service
    echo "%%~G" service unknown/not found
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>NUL`, `&&`, `||` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: I appreciate your help. I was shooting for a 1 liner like below;
so I can just ass each service name. One for disable one for manual one for automatic. Is there a way just to loop through a list of services?

    :start
    cd c:\windows\System32
    for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%i in ('TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME eq %userdomain%\%username%" /FI "STATUS eq running"') do (
    echo %%i
    if not "%%i"=="svchost.exe" (
    if not "%%i"=="explorer.exe" (
    if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
    if not "%%i"=="tasklist.exe" (
    )
    )
    )
    )

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your help. I was shooting for a 1 liner like below;
so I can just ask each service name. One for disabled one for manual one for automatic. Is there a way just to loop through a list of services?

```
:start
cd c:\windows\System32
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%i in ('TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME eq %userdomain%\%username%" /FI "STATUS eq running"') do (
echo %%i
if not "%%i"=="svchost.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="explorer.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="tasklist.exe" (
)
)
)
)
```